# Flutter web url not changing when i host it in aws S3

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3

I host flutter web in S3 and point it's index from php. Content is coming but url not changing.

I try to host Flutter web in aws S3 and point it's index from php. After this content is coming but on redirect the url not changing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.